# Select and looping over differences in two directories linux

Tags: linux, bash, file, sh

I have bash script that that loops through files in the raw folder and puts them into the audio folder. This works just fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH_IN=('/nas/data/customers/test2/raw/')
PATH_OUT=('/nas/data/customers/test2/audio/')

mkdir -p /nas/data/customers/test2/audio
IFS=$'\n'
find $PATH_IN -type f -name '*.wav' -exec basename {} \; | while read -r file; do
    sox -S ${PATH_IN}${file} -e signed-integer ${PATH_OUT}${file}
done
```

My issue is that, as the folders grow I do not want to run the script on the files that has already been converted, so I would like to loop over only the files that has not been converted yet. I.e the files only in raw but not in audio.

I found the function

> diff audio raw

That can I do just that, but I cannot find a good way to incorporate this into my bash script. Any help or nudges in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered moving the raw files to another directory once they've been processed?

Comment: Need to keep them in the same directory as it is an SFTP server we do not control

Comment: Keep a list of all files you have already converted in a textfile, and when running over the files, first check whether or not the filename is already present in that textfile.

Comment: That would indeed be one solution, but would require me to keep track of an additional file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

`diff <(ls -1a $PATH_OUT) <(ls -1a $PATH_IN) | grep -E ">" | sed -E 's/> //'`

The first part will diff the files on both folders, the second part will filter out to get only the additions, and the third one will clean the list from the diff symbols to get just the names.